# Running multiple iterations of K-Means with different values for number of centroids

Tags: r, variables

I have a large dataset and I am trying to run a K-means cluster analysis. However, I want to repeat this with multiple iterations by changing the number of centroids. Here's what I've done so far:

```
# import data

week1 <- read.csv("WEEK1.csv", header = TRUE)
week2 <- read.csv("WEEK2.csv", header = TRUE)
week3 <- read.csv("WEEK3.csv", header = TRUE)
week4 <- read.csv("WEEK4.csv", header = TRUE)

data <- rbind(week1, week2, week3, week4)

# variable names

for(i in 1:50){
  assign(paste("cluster", i, sep = ""), i)    
}
```

I've spent a long time trying to figure out how to "recall" my cluster variables in a for loop so that I can do something like this:

```
for (i in 1:50){
  cluster[i] <- kmeans(data, i, nstart = 1)
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where is the problem with using an array?

Comment: Not sure there is one, I'm pretty new to R so I don't know all the different ways I could go about doing this. I had tried to create a data frame and a matrix but wasn't able to successfully store the kmeans results in either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could help, put the various numbers of clusters in a vector, and store the result in a list. My example is with 3 max centroids, and I'm using the `mtcars` dataset, due you have not posted your data.

```
vector <- c()                                             # an empty vector
for(i in 1:3){                                            # a loop that creates the
                                                          # various n of clusters
   vector[i] <- assign(paste("cluster", i, sep = ""), i)         
}
```

Now we can create the list of `kmeans`:

```
list_k <- list()                                          # an empty list
for (i in vector){                                        # fill it with the kmeans
  list_k[[i]] <- kmeans(mtcars, i, nstart = 1)
}
```

To have access to each kmeans, you can use this:

```
list_k[[3]]
```

To have access to each element of each list, this:

```
list_k[[3]][1]
```